# Angular child to child data sharing in same level

Tags: angular

I have an angular application with parent and child. In which parent to child and child to parent data sharing can be done using `@input/output()` methods using its event and property binding. How can we pass data between child to child.

[image]

Can any one explain with a good example and code in fiddle?

Comment: Two ways come to mind. 1) you can have all the communication done through the parent, downfall is that the children will always need a parent to communicate with. Or 2), you can create a service where the children observe properties and can pass data amongst each other. I would suggest the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of Shared Service to pass the data between two child components, while use @input event emitter to send data from parent to child.

```
 <div style="background-color: red; padding: 10px;">
    <div>{{counter}}</div>
    <button (click)="increment()">increment from parent</button>
    <app-child [(counter)]="counter"></app-child>
    <app-child [counter]="counter" (counterChange)="counter=$event"></app-child>
  </div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-wn7ns8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Yep.Sajee as always is right. Use the reactive approach for smart/dumb components

Comment: @Sajeetharan it is child1 and child2. I mean app-child1 and app-child2. 2 separate components